Podrian indicarme como agregar en este grafico de matplotlib las fechas?
Tengo este codigo que incluyo a continuacion y necesito agregar los años en el eje x. Los datos que tengo es la fecha completa de dia, mes y año, pero solo quiero que aparezcan los 10 años que incluye mi dataset
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.plot(data['Date'], data['Adj Close'], marker='o', linestyle='-')
plt.title('Subida de Precios de Acciones por Fecha')
plt.xlabel('Fecha')
plt.ylabel('Precio de las Acciones')
plt.grid(True)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()


Hola Lucía, sería de gran ayuda que mostraras un ejemplo de los datos de esas dos columna (como texto) y el tipo de dato de la columna Date ¿Es datetime64 u otra cosa? La estructura del DataFrame es importante porque no queda claro si tienes 10 filas (una por año), una por mes o una por día, etc Entiendo que en los ticks solo quieres que aparezca el año, pero si tienes más de una fila por año y gráficas todas las filas ¿la marca debe aparecer centrada, al inicio del año, al final?

Intenta siempre proveer un [mcve] y aclara lo mejor que puedas el resultado que esperas, ayuda a reproducir el problema y obtendrás respuestas mucho antes y más exactas.
